# How to make a function in a for loop or lapply loop in a tabItem dashboard shiny

Tags: r, shiny, lapply, dashboard, tabitem

I'm making a ShinyDashboard program and I have some troubles in finding a way to make a loop in the dashboardBody to catch MenuItems. This is a simple example of what I'm trying to fix:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs) 
library(shinydashboard)

VecNames=c("A","B","C","D","E")

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "My Page"),
dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenuOutput("sideBar_menu_UI")),
dashboardBody(
uiOutput("body_UI"),
uiOutput("test_UI")
) 
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 
output$sideBar_menu_UI <- renderMenu({
sidebarMenu(id = "sideBar_Menu",
            menuItem("Menu 1", tabName="menu1_tab", icon =       icon("calendar"),
                     lapply(1:length(VecNames), function(i) {
                       menuSubItem(VecNames[i], tabName = VecNames[i]  ,icon = icon("angle-right"))
                     })
                     ),
            menuItem("Menu 2", tabName="menu2_tab", icon =  icon("database"))
 )
 }) 
output$test_UI <- renderUI ({
A=tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "menu1_tab", uiOutput("menu1_UI")),    



 #      lapply(1:5, function(i){
 #        tabItem(tabName = VecNames[i], uiOutput(paste0("Menu",i)))        
 #      }),
  tabItem(tabName = VecNames[1], uiOutput(paste0("Menu",1))),
  tabItem(tabName = VecNames[2], uiOutput(paste0("Menu",2))),
  tabItem(tabName = VecNames[3], uiOutput(paste0("Menu",3))),
  tabItem(tabName = VecNames[4], uiOutput(paste0("Menu",4))),
  tabItem(tabName = VecNames[5], uiOutput(paste0("Menu",5))),      


  tabItem(tabName = "menu2_tab", uiOutput("menu2_UI"))
 )
 })
 output$body_UI <- renderUI ({
 p("Default content in body outsite any sidebar menus.")
 })
 output$menu1_UI <- renderUI ({
 box("Menu 1 Content")
 })
 output$menu2_UI <- renderUI ({
 box("Menu 2 Content")
 })

 lapply(1:5, function(i){
 output[[paste0("Menu",i)]]<- renderUI({
  box(paste0("Menu",i))
  })
  })

   })

 runApp(list(ui= ui, server = server))
```

I want something like the following code but it seems that lapply doesn't accept tabItem as a function

```
  #      lapply(1:5, function(i){
  #        tabItem(tabName = VecNames[i], uiOutput(paste0("Menu",i)))        
  #      })
```

Any help?
Thank you for your answers on advanced

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is, that you try to use a list of `tabItem` objects as an argument for `tabItems`, but this is invalid according to the documentation of `tabItems`.

> `tabItems(...)`
>
> `...` Items to put in the container. Each item should be a tabItem.

`do.call` can be used to resolve this issue. Basically, `do.call` operates as follows.

```
add <- function(x, y){x + y}
do.call(add, list(4, 3)) # same as add(4, 3)
## 7
```

So you basically want to use the list returned from `lapply` as the second argument to `do.call` while the first argument is the function to call (`tabItems`).

```
output$test_UI <- renderUI ({
  items <- c(
    list(tabItem(tabName = "menu1_tab", uiOutput("menu1_UI"))),
    lapply(1:5, function(i){
      tabItem(tabName = VecNames[i], uiOutput(paste0("Menu",i)))        
    })
  )
  do.call(tabItems, items)
})
```