# Is there a way in which we can make the sidebarMenu -> menuItems dynamic?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm making a ShinyDashboard program and I have some troubles in finding a way to make a loop in the MenuItems. Specifically, I am looking for something that can replace the following lines:

```
menuItem(
  "Section1",
  tabName = "Section1",
  startExpanded = T,
  menuSubItem("Sub Menu 1", tabName = "tab1"),
  menuSubItem("Sub Menu 2", tabName = "tab2")
  ),

menuItem(
  "Section2",
  tabName = "Section2",
  startExpanded = T,
  menuSubItem("Sub Menu 1", tabName = "tab1"),
  menuSubItem("Sub Menu 2", tabName = "tab2")
  )
```

Here is what I tried :

```
lapply(1:2, function(i){
       do.call(menuItem, c(text = paste0("Section",i), tabName =paste0("Section",i), startExpanded = T,
       lapply(1:2, function(j) {
           menuSubItem(text = paste0("sub menu ", j), tabName=paste0("tab",j))
       }
       )))
  })
```

It is throwing the following error:

> *Error in : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors*

I went through a post that does something similar with dashboardBody -> tabItems

[How to make a function in a for loop or lapply loop in a tabItem dashboard shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909890/how-to-make-a-function-in-a-for-loop-or-lapply-loop-in-a-tabitem-dashboard-shiny)

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for, but the code below dynamically creates those two menu items along with their subitems.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "My Page"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenuOutput("sidebar_menu")),
  dashboardBody(
    NULL
  ) 
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) { 
  output$sidebar_menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(id = "tab",

                menuItem("Section1", tabName="Section2", startExpanded = T,
                         lapply(1:2, function(i) {
                           menuSubItem(paste0("Sub Menu ",i), tabName = paste0("tab",i))
                         })
                ),
                menuItem("Section2", tabName="Section2", startExpanded = T,
                         lapply(1:2, function(i) {
                           menuSubItem(paste0("Sub Menu ",i), tabName = paste0("tab",i))
                         })
                )
    )


  })

})
runApp(list(ui= ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for your response....this code generates SubItems dynamically not the menuItem as it is fixing Section 1 and Section 2. I am looking for something that creates these sections dynamically. Please let me know if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```
output$menu <- renderMenu(
    {
      sidebarMenu(id = "sbm",
                  lapply(1:10, function(i){
                    do.call(menuItem, c(text = paste0("Section",i), tabName = paste0("Section",i), startExpanded = T,
                                        lapply(1:2, function(j) {
                                          menuSubItem(text = paste0("sub menu ", j), tabName=paste0("tab",j))
                                        }
                                        )))
                  }
                    ))
      })
```